# Omit certain characters from Rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, data-cleaning

I have a column that has Serial Numbers but some of them has unwanted characters attached with the Serial Number:-

```
8009914407
MCO
8558201722
US2
US3
MCO
7272950703
US2
MCO
NULL
8558201722
7272505721_R2C
8002094684
8558088363_AAC
NULL
US2
```

These are some of the entries from a Column in a SQL Table.

I want to omit all the characters including and after the Underscore. For example, these values would become this:-

> 8558088363_AAC = 8558088363
>
> 7272505721_R2C = 7272505721

And keep rest of the rows as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(serial_number, '_', 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3124328f46d45ecd8ec5fded32af65d) is a db<>fiddle.

In SQL Server, the code is:

```
select left(serial_number, charindex('_', serial_number + '_') - 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using SQL Server and mistakenly added the Tag for MySQL. Now, in SQL Server, this function: "substring_index()" is not available. I found some answers to create a function that resembles "substring_index()" function but my Office's DB doesn't allow us to create a function !

Is there still a work around this ?

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant. Thank you. There are so many similar questions and answers regarding this on Stackoverflow ... people usually advice to create a 15-20 lines function to replace "substring_index()" function. But your solution is beautifully elegant. Thanks once again @Gordon Linoff ...